# Split the single alphanumeric string column to two columns as numbers and alphabets

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I have a single alphanumeric string column that has to be split into two different columns: numbers and alphabet.
But the thing is we just need to split the first part of numbers from string and the remaining alphanumeric should remain same in 2nd column

For example:

| Col A |
| --- |
| 2 Nutsx20mm |
| 2 200 jibs50 |
| 3 200 |
| 5 |
| 8 Certs 20 |

Expected:

| A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Nutsx20mm |
| 2 200 | jibs50 |
| 3 200 | null |
| 5 | null |
| 8 | Certs 20 |

I have tried out, It works correctly but fails when the string is just a 4 digit number with space.

```
code:
df_tab["Col A"].str.extract(r'(\d+)(?: (\S.+))?$')
```

The output I get is below table:

| A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Nutsx20mm |
| 2 | 200 jibs50 |
| 3 | 200 |
| 5 |  |
| 8 | Certs 20 |

Comment: `+` means "one or more". You want "zero or more", which is `*`.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the comment, But my code fails only when there is any space between the first numbers. For example: "2 200 jibs50" should come as "2 200 " and "jibs50" but am getting as "2" and "200 jibs50"

Comment: Then you should have said that in the question. Please delete your comment and correct your question. (You say it works correctly except for when it's just a four digit number with a space.)

Comment: @MatBailie, I have mentioned in the question tables how the expected output should be.

Comment: Then correct the words above that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change in the regex works

**Code:**

```
df["Col A"].str.extract(r'([\d\s]+)(?: (\S.+))?$')
```

**Change:**

Previous your regex was matching only digits. Changed it to match digits and numbers.

**Output:**

```
2   Nutsx20mm
2 200   jibs50
3 200   NaN
5   NaN
8   Certs 20
```

Comment: Won't that take `1234 ` and retain the space with the number?

Comment: @MatBailie if it was just numbers with trailing space then yes i.e.) "1234 ". If it number with multiple space then words yes [1234      abc]. If it was numbers with space then no

Answer (score 1):

```
df_tab["Col A"].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\s\d+)*)(?: (\S.+))?$')
```

This will capture any additional number only blocks of text.

Tested with:

```
2 300
2 300 400
2 nuttx20mm
2 300 mutt
```

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is useful for writing and testing regex and is what I used for this answer.